# How to convert into system of differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I transform $y''-3y'-10y=0$ into a system of two first order diff eqs and how do I solve it?

I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $y'=z$ and rearrange.

Comment: tell me if you are acquainted with eigenvalues and eigenvectors, to write the solution in those terms

Comment: well, I still don't know how to finish it. and No Im not really, just a bit

Comment: the system gonna be $$y'=z,$$ $$z'=10y+3z$$

Comment: the general solution is $y=Ke^{5t}+Le^{-2t}$, for some constants $K,L$.